# unable to resolve dependency for akamai edgegrid API

Tags: maven, akamai

I am trying to use akamai edgegrid API for invalidating akamai chache. I have added below dependency in my pom.xml, but my bundle keeps in installed state. Below are more details-

pom.xml dependency-

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.akamai.edgegrid</groupId>
<artifactId>edgegrid-signer-apache-http-client</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Bundle is in installed state, on felix console it says-

```
Imported Packages   com.akamai.edgegrid.signer -- Cannot be resolved
```

error.log says -

```
Unable to resolve 497.82: missing requirement [497.82] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.akamai.edgegrid.signer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `<scope>provided</scope>` , it means this jar will be used during compile time and during run time it will use the jar available on the run time environment. Unfortunately edgegrid-signer-apache-http-client-2.1.0.jar is not available on the AEM instance. 
To resolve the issue, Do not use `<scope>provided</scope>` .
Updated POM -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.akamai.edgegrid</groupId>
<artifactId>edgegrid-signer-apache-http-client</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Before deploying the bundle on AEM, extract the jar and check edgegrid-signer-apache-http-client.jar , edgegrid-signer-core.jar, httpclient.jar, httpcore.jar should be part of the bundle.

Hopefully it will solve your issue. All the best. 
Please let me know if you still face any issue. 
-Mrutyunjaya

Comment: I have added below dependencies-

<dependency><groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId><artifactId>httpclient</artifactId><version>4.5.3</version></dependency>

<dependency><groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId><artifactId>httpcore</artifactId><version>4.3.2</version></dependency>

<dependency><groupId>com.akamai.edgegrid</groupId><artifactId>edgegrid-signer-core</artifactId><version>2.1.0</version></dependency>

<dependency><groupId>com.akamai.edgegrid</groupId><artifactId>edgegrid-signer-apache-http-client</artifactId><version>2.1.0</version></dependency>
Please suggest