# com.akamai.edgegrid.signer Cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, osgi, aem, akamai

Running into an issue that is driving me nuts. Implementing Amakai Edgegrid auth into AEM (6.0 SP3) and it's preventing my primary services bundle from starting since it's not a OSGi bundle.

Exact same issue as noted in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117251/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-akamai-edgegrid-api), but this doesn't solve anything, as I never included scope for the dependency to begin with..

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.akamai.edgegrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>edgegrid-signer-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.akamai.edgegrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>edgegrid-signer-apache-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

> com.akamai.edgegrid.signer -- Cannot be resolved
>   com.akamai.edgegrid.signer.apachehttpclient -- Cannot be resolved

Error log..

> *ERROR* [qtp1187594825-933] org.apache.felix.http.jetty
>   %bundles.pluginTitle: Cannot start
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
>   com.aem.common-service [478]: Unable to resolve 478.21:
>   missing requirement [478.21] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=com.akamai.edgegrid.signer))
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
>   com.aem.common-service [478]: Unable to resolve 478.21:
>   missing requirement [478.21] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=com.akamai.edgegrid.signer)  at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3980)
>     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2043)    at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)  at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)  at
>   org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BundlesServlet.doPost(BundlesServlet.java:364)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:450)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I have also tried using Export-Package and Embed-Dependency using maven-bundle-plugin. This appears to solve the issue at first, but it cascades to additional issues which also prevent the main bundle from starting..

Comment: Using Embed-Dependency for the edgegrid-signer(-core?) jar is the right thing to do. You just have to resolve the next issue and so on until it works.

Comment: I integrated with Akamai using these dependencies (via Gradle):

    libs 'edgegrid-auth:edgegrid-auth:1.0.0'
    libs 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.22.0'

With those I was able to write AEM code to invoke Akamai APIs, such as Fast Purge.  I don't know if it will help, but you can try that.

Comment: @gjoranv I've tried doing that already. Unfortunately once I get to the third or fourth one it turns into around 30+ unresolved bundles..

Comment: @Shawn thanks for the tip, but we're not really using gradle at all.. I'd hate to add another variable to the mix..

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use Gradle--just that you import the same dependencies.  I listed a Gradle example, so you'd need to translate the syntax.

Comment: @Shawn got it, thanks for clarifying. Misunderstood :) I will try that, thank you.

Comment: @Shawn edgegrid-auth package is an old variation from the looks of it. Can't even find that dependency any longer. Sounds like they've reworked that. Have a call with Akamai tomorrow, hopefully they can help resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work with Martin over at Akamai to get a new version 4.0.0 of the edgegrid dependency released. The changes remove a number of unnecessary dependencies, and also make it easier to work with the maven-bundle-plugin to work in OSGi.

The resulting maven-bundle-plugin configuration for the bundle in which this dependency is used..

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-Activator>com.foo.common.service.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Export-Package>com.foo.common.service.*;com.google.zxing.*;com.akamai.edgegrid.*;version=${project.version}</Export-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>commons-lang3,ooxml-schemas,jackson-core,gson,sitemapgen4j,edgegrid-signer-apache-http-client</Embed-Dependency>
                    <!-- <Sling-Bundle-Resources>/var/classes</Sling-Bundle-Resources> <Sling-Initial-Content>SLINGINF/sling/servlets/;overwrite:=true;uninstall:=true;path:=/apps/sling/servlets,SLING-INF/public/;overwrite:=true;uninstall:=true;path:=/apps/public</Sling-Initial-Content> -->
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Once this was added, using the version 4.0.0 of the edgegrid dependency, my bundle started right up.